# Purge tool missing from 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, purgetool

I remember using Purge Tool GUI, in Tridion 2009 SP1 and 2011.

[image: Purge Tool]

But could not able to find out the same in 2013 SP1. The documentation on sdlliveconntent highlights only on the Powershell commands that we can use to purge the old items.

Can anyone please confirm if this tool doesn't exist anymore in higher versions of Tridion??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, purge tool has been replaced by Powershell scripts.. this would make easier for scheduling jobs for purging.

On Tridion machine, you can use powershell command "help Remove-OldTcmItems" to check the available parameters for the command....

Answer (score 8):

Correct. The purge tool and other DB utilities have been replaced by PowerShell commands and scripts.

To purge and reindex data, see the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-00C1DEE2-8281-4EA8-A8B5-4E9EC3AA3C55) (login required)